# Copy paste(clipboard) works differently in ssh and local system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, copy-paste, clipboard

I am using my local system to copy some text using

```
ctrl + c
```

In ssh i use this command to paste

```
shift + insert
```

The above works fine

Now i using this command to copy from ssh

```
ctrl + insert
```

But i my local system i used this command to paste it

```
ctrl + v
```

But the above command pastes different text from which i copied from ssh

but inside the ssh

```
shift + insert
```

Pastes the exact text which i copied

How to copy a text from ssh and paste it in local system(I am using ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu (and other distros which use X windows system) you can simply select the text with your mouse and then paste it to another window by clicking middle button (wheel) on your mouse. It is far easier than fiddling around with hotkeys on the keyboard.

Relating to your question - I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and I've just tried to replicate your issue - and I couldn't. For me it works as it should across windows and terminals with ssh's in them.